# Why did mysql data ownership change to systemd-journal-remote after running a docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, archlinux

I have the mysql database stored in `/home/mysql` instead of `/var/lib/mysql`. The directory used to be owned by `mysql`. However, when I run the command `docker-compose up` with this yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
     - /home/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.4
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms750m -Xmx750m"
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
  site:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app"
    links:
      - mariadb:mysql
    environment:
      - DOCKER_IP=172.19.0.2
    depends_on: ['elasticsearch','mariadb']
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

The docker container is able to run, but the entire folder and files in `/home/mysql` are owned by `systemd-journal-remote`, which causes the `node` server fails to connect to `mariadb`. I have to stop the docker instance, restore the mysql folder ownership and delete `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`.

Why does mounting `/home/mysql` cause such a fatal problem?

Update:

My solution is to add `user: "mysql"`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
     - /home/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    user: "mysql"
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.4
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms750m -Xmx750m"
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
  site:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app"
    links:
      - mariadb:mysql
    environment:
      - DOCKER_IP=172.19.0.2
    depends_on: ['elasticsearch','mariadb']
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start Docker's container with `--user` parameter. If you do this and set the same `uid:gid` as owner of the MySQL storage you will no have problems with permissions. You have to check how exactly to do this in Docker Compose because I show you example for normal command line execution

Comment: Thank you. adding `user: "89"` fixes the ownership problem. But everytime after I stop using container and launch mariadb via `systemctl start mariadb`, it doesnt start unless I delete `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`

Comment: Hmm, did you check permission of these files? Do they have normal user/group as owner or the root?

Comment: Just fount that those two log files are under the `root` group after running the container. It was under `mysql` group before.

Comment: And another question do you use official image of MariaDB from Docker's Hub/Store?

Comment: The docker compose will download the official image for me. I've fixed the problem. Those two log files won't change ownership if I use `user:"mysql"` instead of `user:"89".` in the yml file

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `uid` of your user `systemd-journal-remote` is the same as `uid` of user `mysqld` in container. Check with `ls -n`. To avoid confusion, either use common `uid`s, perhaps test as `root:root` with `chmod o+rwx`.

Comment: my `systemd-journal-remote` uid is 999 , which is very likely the case, still trying to find out how to change the container mariadb uid